# Redirect .html extension to no html extension

Tags: .htaccess

I am currently using this rule in my .htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/billing/
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

And was wondering it it were to be possible for it to automatically redirect any links that have .html at the end e.g examplewebsite.com/fishing.html to examplewebsite.com/fishing

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add this redirect rule for `.html` removal **before your earlier rule**:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /([^.]+)\.html[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=302,L,NE]
```